# Minibatch SGD gradient computation- average or sum

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to understand how the gradients are computed when using miinibatch SGD. I have implemented it in CS231 online course, but only came to realize that in intermediate layers the gradient is basically the sum over all the gradients computed for each sample (the same for the implementations in Caffe or Tensorflow). It is only in the last layer (the loss) that they are averaged by the number of samples. 
Is this correct? if so, does it mean that since in the last layer they are  averaged, when doing backprop, all the gradients are also averaged automatically?
Thanks!

Comment: How is this related to TensorFlow?

Comment: I tagged it because in the tensorflow implementation is done like that, also people in that community usually are aware of the low level implementations (maybe not you) and might help to answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is best to understand why SGD works first.

Normally, what a neural network actually is, a very complex composite function of an input vector x, a label y(or target variable, changes according to whether the problem is classification or regression) and some parameter vector, w. Assume that we are working on classification. We are actually trying to do a maximum likelihood estimation (actually MAP estimation since we are certainly going to use L2 or L1 regularization, but this is too much technicality for now) for variable vector w. Assuming that samples are independent; then we have the following cost function:

```
p(y1|w,x1)p(y2|w,x2) ... p(yN|w,xN)
```

Optimizing this wrt to w is a mess due to the fact that all of these probabilities are multiplicated (this will produce an insanely complicated derivative wrt w). We use log probabilities instead (taking log does not change the extreme points and we divide by N, so we can treat our training set as a empirical probability distribution, p(x) )

```
J(X,Y,w)=-(1/N)(log p(y1|w,x1) + log p(y2|w,x2) + ... + log p(yN|w,xN))
```

This is the actual cost function we have. What the neural network actually does is to model the probability function p(yi|w,xi). This can be a very complex 1000+ layered ResNet or just a simple perceptron.

Now the derivative for w is simple to state, since we have an addition now:

```
dJ(X,Y,w)/dw = -(1/N)(dlog p(y1|w,x1)/dw + dlog p(y2|w,x2)/dw + ... + dlog p(yN|w,xN)/dw)
```

Ideally, the above is the actual gradient. But this batch calculation is not easy to compute. What if we are working on a dataset with 1M training samples? Worse, the training set may be a stream of samples x, which has an infinite size.

The Stochastic part of the SGD comes into play here. Pick m samples with m << N randomly and uniformly from the training set and calculate the derivative by using them:

```
 dJ(X,Y,w)/dw =(approx) dJ'/dw = -(1/m)(dlog p(y1|w,x1)/dw + dlog p(y2|w,x2)/dw + ... + dlog p(ym|w,xm)/dw)
```

Remember that we had an empirical (or actual in the case of infinite training set) data distribution p(x). The above operation of drawing m samples from p(x) and averaging them actually produces the unbiased estimator, dJ'/dw, for the actual derivative dJ(X,Y,w)/dw. What does that mean? Take many such m samples and calculate different dJ'/dw estimates, average them as well and you get dJ(X,Y,w)/dw very closely, even exactly, in the limit of infinite sampling. It can be shown that these noisy but unbiased gradient estimates will behave like the original gradient in the long run. On the average, SGD will follow the actual gradient's path (but it can get stuck at a different local minima, all depends on the selection of the learning rate). The minibatch size m is directly related to the inherent error in the noisy estimate dJ'/dw. If m is large, you get gradient estimates with low variance, you can use larger learning rates. If m is small or m=1 (online learning), the variance of the estimator dJ'/dw is very high and you should use smaller learning rates, or the algorithm may easily diverge out of control.

Now enough theory, your actual question was

> It is only in the last layer (the loss) that they are averaged by the number of samples. Is this correct? if so, does it mean that since in the last layer they are averaged, when doing backprop, all the gradients are also averaged automatically? Thanks!

Yes, it is enough to divide by m in the last layer, since the chain rule will propagate the factor (1/m) to all parameters once the lowermost layer is multiplied by it. You don't need to do separately for each parameter, this will be invalid.

Comment: This answer is extremely helpful and solved another question that I had about why should we maximize the log likelihood instead of just the likelihood. Thank you so much!

Comment: the super popular deep learning.ai course seems to divide by m for every layer. See my question for more details https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33357/should-the-partials-be-averaged-once-or-multiple-times-for-backprop

Comment: I saw it, If you contiunally divide by 1/m every layer, you are certainly won't have any meaningful derivative left in the first layer. If you have L layers, the first layer's derivative will be scaled by (1/m)^L. Think of a ResNet-50, having L=50. You surely won't have any error signal left. This is most probably a notation abuse.

Answer (score 2):

In the last layer they are averaged, and in the previous are summed. The summed gradients in previous layers are summed across different nodes from the next layer, not by the examples. This averaging is done only to make the learning process behave similarly when you change the batch size -- everything should work the same if you sum all the layers, but decrease the learning rate appropriately.

Comment: so for example, let's say I have a fully connected layer, sth like:
y=XW, where X is an Nxd matrix (N samples with dimension d), and W is dxM (M output nodes). then y is NxM. Now if we have the dL/dy (NxM), then  dL/dW =dy/dW * dL/dy, then dL/dW=X_transpose * dL/dy; in this case, I think dL/dW is adding the gradients coming for each individual sample. is this right?

Comment: No, it's adding the gradients for each __node__ in y (M). Assuming L is an average over samples, dL/dy is an average as well, but it have some dimensions according to the number of nodes in the output layer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am bit confused I am sorry, 
but if dL/dy is an average, why does it have size NxM (like one gradient for each sample)?

Comment: Being an average is just a matter of a constant. It doesn't change the shape. I am also a bit confused about the shapes here, but I think that if L maps N examples to 1 value (either summing or averaging them), dL/dy will not have the shape dependent on N. e.g. if L = sum_i y_i (M -> 1), then dL/dy = [1, ..., 1] (M -> 1). The shape of y doesn't matter here.